# Accessing variable in Map<Class, String> by Index

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

I have a LinkedHashMap with a class as the Key as such:

```
private final Map<Files, String> list = new LinkedHashMap<Files,String>();
```

Files is a class consisting of 3 variables:

```
class Files {
public String file;
public String duration;
public String status;
}
```

Now I need to access the variables in Files using a index. I know that LinkedHashMap does not allow retrieving values using Index, so I tried this:

```
List<Entry<Files,String>> randAccess = new ArrayList<Entry<Files,String>>(list.entrySet());
```

Using `randAccess.get(index)` I can retrieve the Key itself, but not the specific variables inside the class. So the output is somethinglike Files@6aa91761=String.

I want to be able to get the variable, something like: `list.Files.status.Get(index)` would return return the value of "status" at the right Index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the Files variables from the Map.Entry using [`.getKey()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getKey%28%29). From there you can get the status field directly.

```
randAccess.get(index).getKey().status
```